# dplyr: if_else is greedy

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to `mutate` a new variable conditionally on the value of another variable using `if_else`, but `if_else` insists on computing all the values, and then conditionally replacing the values in the final vector.

This behaviour is problematic when the function that results in the final values for some cases cannot be computed for other cases:

```
df_foo = data_frame(
  rate = sample(c(0, 0.1), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
  pmt = 1000,
  nper = 10
)

df_foo %>% 
  mutate(
    if_else(
      rate > 0,
      optiRum::PV(rate = rate, pmt = -pmt, nper = nper),
      0
    )
  )
```

Is there any way to only compute the `TRUE` values when the condition is `TRUE`?

Comment: something like `df_foo %>% group_by(xx = rate > 0) %>% mutate(if_else(xx, sqrt(pmt), 0))` should help you out. replace with your function

Comment: @joel.wilson Thanks. I must admit I was a little surprised by this behavior. Not sure if I should not be. I think that it defeats the purpose of `if_else` if computing both the vectors for all cases. Anyway, your solution should work form the look of it, so thanks for that.

Comment: actually even `df_foo %>% mutate(if_else(rate > 0, sqrt(pmt), 0))` works to be honest!! I'm not sure of the function you are using. recheck the `PV` function actually

Comment: @joel.wilson `sqrt` will obviously not raise an error for any of the values of `pmt` in my sample. You could try to extend the sample space of `pmt` to include negative numbers and see what happens.

Comment: first of all i haven't downvoted nor did i yet vote to close... i left this question since I have no clue about the function you are using actually..

Comment: @joel.wilson That comment was not directed at you. It it had been, it would have started like this one does, with an `@`.

Comment: incase of `if_else()` though you are getting `NA`, i don't think your o/p data is carrying `NA`. That message is because `if_else` evaluates both TRUE and FALSE and then subsets. This is what i think so. unsure though

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem specific to `if_else`, the base version `ifelse` acts the same. From the help file of `ifelse` we can read:

> If `yes` or `no` are too short, their elements are recycled. `yes` will be
>   evaluated if and only if any element of `test` is true, and analogously
>   for `no`.

There is a number of cases where `ifelse` use is inappropriate, and the raising of warnings of errors in one of the conditions is one.

A solution to do what you want (without `dplyr`) is:

```
df_foo$x <- 0
df_foo$x[df_foo$rate > 0] <- with(df_foo[df_foo$rate > 0, ], optiRum::PV(rate, nper, -pmt))
```